# App Engine SDK - Python Release Version 1.9.0 - February 26, 2014 index limit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

The new App Engine SDK - Release Notes Version 1.9.0 - February 26, 2014
Talks about: "The size limit on the Search API is now computed and enforced on a per-index basis, rather than for the app as a whole. The per-index limit is now 10GB. There is no fixed limit on the number of indexes, or on the total amount of Search API storage an application may use.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

Does this mean that the index.yaml file limit of 200 is no longer the limit?

Thanks you.

Comment: Seems it's talking about Search API, not datastore indexes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Lipis were would be the proper place to ask this question? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the datastore index limit is still 200, check this
[GAE  Issue 8305](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8305)

Comment: Thanks, seems like the limit for index.yaml(200) should work the same as this Search API, enforced on a per-ndb basis, rather than for the app as a whole